# New computer build unable to start

Tags: boot, installation, cpu, motherboard

I am building a new computer and I've encountered a problem; once my out of box build was done I tested the computer to see if it could start. It would only power on for like a second then shut down. To be more specific the mother board lights would turn on and the gpu and cpu heatsink fans would start then turn off.

I do not have a case speaker so I can't find out the problem through that. I double checked if my cpu was seated properly and it was. I eventually found out that when the cpu secure chassis/lever was not fully securing the cpu everything would start up fine but the minute the cpu is fully secured it wouldn't work.

What is the problem and what can I do to fix it? For reference all of my parts are new and the mobo is an asus p8 z77-v lk and the cpu is an itel i5-3570k

Comment: Most motherboards come with a mono channel speaker.  I know that ASUS normally provides one, are you sure, your motherboard didn't come with one?

Answer (score 1):

Check wheter you have connected all the power pins in the mother board like 4x4 pin etc.
The problem is with the processor. Either any failure in power or in the socket. Check the socket for any dust. clean it and run it again.

Comment: Another way to isolate the problem is by checking your GPU wattage requirements and what your PSU offers. Although it sounds to me like a CPU issue, I have once isolated the CPU (disliking the idea) by applying a little pressure to the heatsink while the computer boots up. I my case it did and I there for figured out it must be the CPU or Motherboard socket. Next step, tested the CPU in another MB and  the PC started up. Concluded a faulty MB for startup failure. Just be very careful with the pins in the socket of the MB.

Answer (score 0):

Check [CPU Support list](http://support.asus.com/cpusupport/list.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&s=39&m=P8Z77-V%20LK&os=8&hashedid=J4TfLoZ8TXyFAkFb) and update Motherboard BIOS to [latest version.](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8Z77-V_LK/P8Z77-V-LK-ASUS-1402.zip)

For your CPU, BIOS must be [least 0210 version](http://support.asus.com/cpusupport/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&m=P8Z77-V%20LK&cpu=Core%20i5-3570K%20%283.4G,L3:6M,iGPU,4C,77W,rev.E1%29&pcb=ALL&sincebios=0210&memo=).

[How to check your BIOS version.](http://support.asus.com/Repair.aspx?no=563&Slanguage=en)